# Custom method to duplicate an array in javascript

Tags: javascript

How in javascript make a function for array, which will work like this:

```
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
a.duplicate();     // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.duplicate = function () {...};`, but it is not recommended to add custom properties to native prototypes.

Comment: do you like to get a new array or mutate `a`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following, using [Array.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
a.push(...a);
console.log(a);
```

Or can add a prototype function (**Mutates Original**)

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
Array.prototype.duplicate = function(){
     this.push(...this); // mutates the original array
}
a.duplicate();
console.log(a);
```

Or can add a prototype function (**Creates New**)

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
Array.prototype.duplicate = function(){
     return [...this, ...this]; // creates new
}
console.log(a.duplicate()); // duplicated array
console.log(a); // no change
```

Comment: Thanks! It's very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Add a new function into the `Array.prototype` with name `duplicate`.

If you want to return a new array

```js
Array.prototype.duplicate = function () {
  return [...this, ...this];
}

const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const b = a.duplicate();
console.log(b);
```

Or mutate the original one

```js
Array.prototype.duplicate = function () {
  this.splice(0,0, ...this);
}

const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

a.duplicate();
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use `[...a,...a]` to get new array without modifying the original array

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

 

Array.prototype.duplicate = function(){
     return [...this,...this]
}


console.log(a.duplicate())
console.log("Orignal", a)
```

In case you don't know what `...` is, It's called [**`spread syntax`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Answer (score 1):

Create a new prototype as below:

```
Array.prototype.duplicate = function() {
    var length = this.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
        this.push(this[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code -

```
function duplicate(coll) {

    return coll.concat(coll);
}

duplicate([1, 2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function on array by adding to its prototype (as commented by Teemu).

Your requirements are not very clear, but the following will return an array as in your example:

```
Array.prototype.duplicate = function() {
    return this.concat(this);
}
```